# Java Fxml null pointer exception (Even when the id's are same)

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

This is my controller **IndexController.java**:

```
  import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

import javafx.stage.Stage;




public class IndexController {

    @FXML private GridPane mainlayout;

   @FXML
    private void initialize() { }    


    public Stage getPrimaryStage(){
        //mainlayout is null everytime
        if(mainlayout == null){
            System.out.println("mainLayout is null");
        }

        Stage primary= (Stage) mainlayout.getScene().getWindow();


        return primary;
    }


}
```

This is my fxml code **index.fxml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane   xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" vgap="10" hgap="10" alignment="TOP_LEFT"  fx:controller="com.storehouse.uiController.IndexController" fx:id="mainlayout"  >
     <stylesheets>
         <URL value="@../css/index.css"></URL>
     </stylesheets>   

     <fx:include source="menu.fxml"/>

    <Pane fx:id="fragment" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"   >
   </Pane> 
</GridPane>
```

I am getting a null Pointer exception because of **instance variable mainlayout is null.**
I am stuck with this for hours now and I really couldnt see anythhing. Can someone please tell me how to fix this!!

**StackTrace:**

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.storehouse.uiController.IndexController.getPrimaryStage(IndexController.java:35)
    at com.storehouse.workers.IndexWorker.getPrimaryStage(IndexWorker.java:25)
    at com.storehouse.uiController.NewBoxDialogController.showDialog(NewBoxDialogController.java:37)
    at com.storehouse.workers.NewBoxWorker.showBox(NewBoxWorker.java:27)
    at com.storehouse.uiController.MenuController.createNewBox(MenuController.java:33)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: Where's your stacktrace? Not posting a stacktrace suggests that you're posting this without first checking similar NPE type questions -- not good -- please fix!

Comment: sorry i am new to this place give me a min i will post it

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Can you please tell me whats wrong with my code

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if this is going to help anybody but what i found out that any instance variable with a **@FXML** will not be initalized until

```
@FXML
private void initilize(){}
```

is called. So in my problem I was trying to access the variable but initialize method was never called.

Comment: `@FXML`-annotated fields are initialized as part of the `load()` method of the `FXMLLoader`. Your answer doesn't really make any sense, because if you specify a `fx:controller` attribute (and don't use a `controllerFactory`, which you surely would have included), there is no way to get a reference to the controller before the `load()` method completes. So this answer doesn't really explain the exception.

Comment: I created a insitance of the controller so the variables were null

Comment: Well of course they would be. The instance you created is not the controller for the FXML you are loading. The null pointer exception has nothing with when the fields are initialised, it is because it was not created by the FXMLLoader.

Comment: I am new to this javafx!! just to make sure! when we specify fx:controller they are loaded by load() method??? actually i thought it was fxml

Comment: There is a [documentation example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/1580/fxml-and-controllers/5125/example-fxml#t=201608200431576918638) that explains how this works.